# Prolog - put two lists together and sort it

Tags: list, prolog

I want to write in Prolog an attribute that is true, if the list `NL` has all the members from `L1` und `L2` AND is sorted.

```
putTogether(L1,L2,NL).
```

If I call `putTogether(L1,L2,X)` it should give me L1 + L2 and that sorted.

The base case is

```
putTogether([],[],[]).
```

imho.

Okay, I forgot to say that I don't want to use built-in predicates. So for example `sort` is not valid.

But I have no idea to implement the rest.

Thanks for helpful hints in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just write one term for combining lists, and another for sorting, then use them both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be just:

```
putTogether(L1, L2, NL) :-
    append(L1, L2, L12),
    sort(L12, NL).
```

This will remove all duplicates, but this is consistent with "the list NL has all the members from L1 und L2 AND is sorted".

*Update.* If you "don't want to use built-in predicates" (probably not allowed to by a teacher) just look in a Prolog book, online or a Prolog system sources how to implement your versions of `append` and `sort`.

Answer (score 1):

The heart of this problem is sorting an unordered list. The easiest sort to implement in Prolog is *merge sort* as it is a natural fit for a linked list. The general algorithm is

- if the list is empty, it's already sorted, just return it.
- if the list is of length 1, it's already sorted, just return it.
- if the list of of length > 1, partition the list into two sublists.
- recursively, merge sort the left half
- recursively, merge sort the right half
- merge the two now-ordered lists.

In Prolog, you can implement it something like this:

```
merge_sort( []     , [] ) .     % the empty list is already sorted
merge_sort( [X|Xs] , Zs ) :-    % for a non-empty list, we ...
  partition( [X|Xs] , L , R ) , % - partition it into two lists of more-or-less equal length
  merge_sort( L , L1 ) ,        % - sort the left half
  merge_sort( R , R1 ) ,        % - sort the right half
  merge( L1 , R1 , Zs )         % - merge the two now-ordered lists into 1
  .                             % Easy!
```

The partitioning process isn't much more difficult:

- while 2 or more items remain in the source list

  - assign 1 time to the left and right sublists
- if the list is non-empty, it has just one item left at this point:

  - assign it to either the left or right sublist (doesn't matter).
- return the left and right sublist

You might notice that what's really going on here is dividing the list into evens and odds, rather than in halves, though the net effect is the same: two lists of roughly equal length, differing in length by not more than 1.

That can be implemented in Prolog along these lines:

```
partition( []      , []     , []     ) .   % the empty list gets partitioned into 2 empty lists
partition( [L]     , [L]    , []     ) .   % a list of length 1 gets partitioned into itself and and empty list
partition( [L,R|T] , [L|Ls] , [R|Rs] ) :-  % for a list of 2+ items, we add 1 each to the left and right halves, 
  partition(T,Ls,Rs)                       % ...and recursively partition the remainder
  .                                        % Easy!
```

Merging two ordered lists is also quite simple:

- while both lists are non-empty

  - take an item A and B from each
  - compare them.
  - if A < B, then add them to the result list in A,B order.
  - if A > B, then add them to the result list in B,A order.
  - if A = B, then the order in which they get added doesn't matter
- if either list is non-empty, add it to the result list.

That can be implement in prolog, thusly:

```
merge( []     , []     , []       ) .   % the merger of two empty lists yields the empty list.
merge( [L|Ls] , []     , [L|Ls]   ) .   % the merger of a non-empty, ordered list with the empty list yields the ordered list
merge( []     , [R|Rs] , [R|Rs]   ) .   % the merger of the empty list with a non-empty, ordered list yields the ordered list
merge( [L|Ls] , [R|Rs] , [X,Y|Zs] ) :-  % the merger of two, non-empty, ordered lists is accomplished by:
  compare(CC,L,R) ,                     % - comparing the heads,
  collate(CC,L,R,X,Y) ,                 % - putting them in the proper order
  merge( Ls , Rs , Zs )                 % - and recursively merging the remainder
  .                                     %

collate(<,X,Y,X,Y) .
collate(>,X,Y,Y,X) .
collate(=,X,Y,X,Y) .
```

Once you have that, the solution to your problem is easy. You've two unordered lists: all you have to do is sort each one and merge them:

```
merge_and_sort( Xs , Ys , Zs ) :- % to merge and sort two unordered lists
  merge_sort(Xs,X1) ,             % - sort the first list
  merge_sort(Ys,Y1) ,             % - sort the second list
  merge(X1,Y1,Zs)                 % - merge the two now-ordered lists
  .                               % Easy!
```